# Python Django динамическое обновление таблицы

Tags: python, django

Есть вопрос. У меня на странице присутствует таблица получения через цикл for из базы данных в которой данные одного столбца постоянно меняются. Как можно реализовать обновление данных в этой таблице без перезагрузки страницы?
Django 4

Comment: Если идти сложным путем, то надо сделать функцию в view, которая будет отдавать ответ в json формате. А на html странице ответ будет парсится через JS. https://pythonru.com/primery/django-ajax

Либо использовать htmx, который позволят обновлять данные, не обновляя страницу, при чем без использования js. https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-build-templates-for-django-applications-with-htmx/

Comment: Я бы предпочел htmx

Answer (score 1):

Динамическое обновление возможно с помощью отправления запросов с самого браузера на какой-либо эндпоинт API сервера.

Пример кода на странице:

```
<div class="some-div">
    ...
</div
<script>
function updateData() {
  fetch('http://example.com/data')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      document.querySelector(".some-div").innerHTML = data
    });
}
</script>
```

Теперь можно вызывать `updateData()` в нужный вам момент. Например можете обновлять информацию по нажатию на кнопку.

Подробнее о fetch можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

В `views.py` нужно добавить такой эндпоинт

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_updated_data(request):
    data = {"foo": "bar"} # Здесь все обращения в базу данных и т.д и т.п.
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Ну и не забудьте добавить в `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('/data', view=views.get_updated_data)
]
```

P.S. Если нужно обновлять информацию на странице двунаправленно, то стоит присмотреться к [WebSockets](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch также можно вызывать циклично (SetInterval)